# Не передаются данные через POST

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте, есть сайт, интернет-магазин.
Используется связка Apache+Nginx, mod_rewrite для ЧПУ.

Проблема с передачей данных с формы методом POST и GET на внутрении страницы типа mysite.ru/basket.html (напрямую index.php передаются).

Предполагаю что проблема кроетса в файле htaccess (хотя файл не редактировался долго и еще при нем, до переезда на новый сервер, работал сайт).
И проблема появилась после переезда на новый сервер.
Может кто то сталкивался?

Файл htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 <filesmatch ".(jpg|gif|png|css)$">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 # ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds" 
 </filesmatch>
</IfModule>

php_flag register_globals  off
php_flag safe_mode  on
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc  on
php_flag session.use_trans_sid on
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag open_basedir off

RewriteEngine   on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^.*$    -   [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.htm    -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/$1/index.htm  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%1.htm  -s
RewriteRule ^.*$ /static/%1.htm [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ -   [L]
RewriteRule ^files/shop/(.*)\.html - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|ico|zip|rar|txt|htm|swf)$    /index.php  [L]

ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему они и должны туда передаваться.

**Перевод хтацкеса на русский.**

Флаг [L] - если произошел вызов (а он происходит если условия вызова соблюдены) то останавливаем обработку. Если условия (*RewriteCond*) не соблюдены, то следующая строка (*RewriteRule*) не выполняется, и урл топает к следующей проверке.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^.*$    -   [L]
```

Если файл с таким именем есть в корне - вызываем.  *Наверное так =)*

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.htm    -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/$1/index.htm  [L]
```

Если существует директория, и если в ней есть не пустой index.htm, вызываем.

(Пример: Запрос *example.com/foo* если есть папка */static/foo* и файл */static/foo/index.htm* то показываем */static/foo/index.htm*.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%1.htm  -s
RewriteRule ^.*$ /static/%1.htm [L]
```

Если файл имеет расширение html, и существует файл static/имяЗапрошенногоФайла/1.htm вызываем.

Пример: Если запрос выглядит так: *example.com/foo.html*,  и существует файл */static/foo/1.html* , то показываем файл */static/foo/1.html*.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ -   [L]
```

Если вызывается файл с расширением php - чудес не делаем, вызывается в точности то, что в адресной строке.

```
RewriteRule ^files/shop/(.*)\.html - [L]
```

Если путь в адресной строке начинается на files/shop/ и заканчивается .html, 
(Пример: example.com/files/shop/*filename*.html ) чудес не делаем, вызывается в точности то, что в адресной строке.

А теперь самое интересное.

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|ico|zip|rar|txt|htm|swf)$    /index.php  [L]
```

**Не торопитесь удалять эту дерективу.**

Эта строка - если расширение файла не похоже ни на одно из вышеперечисленного, то слать на /index.php

Теперь, если вы вызываете файл example.com/file.html, и не существует директории /static/file/1.htm, то данный пойдут на index.php

**>>> Суть ответа <<<**

Если вы наблюдаете подобную ситуацию после переноса, то скорее всего у вас глюкнул обработчик путей, который валяется или подключается к index.php.

Вероятно он может использовать патч от {DOCUMENT_ROOT}, который где-то, возможно, указан в ручную, и его надо сменить.

Либо переопределен *$_SERVER* , и содержит не те данные, которые там должны быть.